# Facebook Activity Feed Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to add the activity feed plugin for my site but it looks like Facebook is deprecating this plugin as of tomorrow.  Are there any alternative ways to get an activity feed to show up on a web page?  This is from the Facebook Developers documentation.

```
Activity Feed

With the release of Graph API v2.3, the Activity Feed plugin is deprecated and will stop working on June 23rd 2015.

The Activity feed displays the most interesting, recent activity taking place on your site, using actions (such as likes) by your friends and other people.
```

Comment: You can use Graph API and Open Graph actions/objects to do similar things.

Comment: But not in any way as easily as just doing a copy/paste of a bit of code. Unless there's some alternative out there that does exactly that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can replace it with the Page Plugin. Good luck!
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Comment: No, the Page plugin does not have the same functionality. Mainly it does not show activity for a domain, but for a fanpage.